# Acces variables from another class PYTHON

Tags: python, pyqt

```
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect_mysql.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.dialog = MainMenu()
    def on_click(self):
        try:
            ip = self.ip.text()
            user = self.user.text()
            password = self.password.text()
            port = self.port.text()
            db = self.db.text()
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
              host=ip,
              user=user,
              passwd=password,
              database=db
                )
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            self.close()
            self.dialog.show()

        except:
            QMessageBox.about(self, "Message", "Something went wrong...")
```

I want to access mucursor from another class. Is it possible to do? Code closes window and opens new window where mysql query is sent.

Comment: It's possible if you inherit that class

Comment: Please, fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, all object attributes are public in Python. All you need to do is save the cursor in the class instance:

```
self.mycursor = mycursor = ...
```

Then from somewhere else,

```
my_window_instance.mycursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a definition that will get the variable within the ExampleApp class:

```
def get_mycursor(self):
    return self.mycursor
```

If you want to access mycursor to redefine it, you could make a set function as well:

```
def set_mycursor(self, newval):
    self.mycursor = newval
```